# Finding notes in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image like this. And I want to find the location of notes. What is the best way to find them ? (They are not circle and they are so small so circlefinder can't find them !)

[image]

[Image of Notes !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQeRT.png)

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting question!  It's definitely going to be hard because there are similar structures to the notes (clefs, sharp/flat signs) in comparison to the notes.  Shape analysis may be difficult here. Do you just want the notes?  What about the surrounding staff lines?  Is it acceptable to have those as part of the extracted result?

Comment: I only want the circle of each notes ! Other lines are not important for me

Comment: Part of the problem may be that notes aren't typically printed circular - they are oval.  Some form of template matching might work - capture a little image of one note head and a few pixels each side.  Then scan the image for things that look similar.

Comment: That's going to be difficult because you have some notes that are filled and some that aren't.  Simon B may be on to something.  Perhaps do a template matching, but you're going to need multiple templates - one for each note that you're going to detect.  In addition, template matching may fail when you get to the quarter notes in the bass staff.  This I'm afraid is too broad of a problem to solve here on a single question.

Comment: I think @SimonB 's template matching idea is promising, maybe with some additional rules to isolate notes from other similar ellipse-shaped objects in the image.

Comment: Ah, but the music is in the rests... `imopen` might remove some of the thinner elements. Following @SimonB's observation that the notes aren't circular, perhaps skewing the image until they are circular would help. But then you'd have to know the proper angle and eccentricity of the ellipses.

Comment: Are you hoping for a solution that works on arbitrary examples, or can you assume that they were all generated by the same tool? Template matching should give great results if you know notes will always look the same, but if you're using scans of scores from different sources then the lack of consistency will definitely give you accuracy issues. What toolboxes do you have available?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a bit of code to get you going...that's not perfect but it was a lof of fun haha.

What I did is to erode the image with a disk structuring element until what was left in the image was shapes the looked the most like circles. Then I eroded again but this time with a line structuring element oriented at an angle close to that of the notes; I figured it's about 15 degrees.

After that, call `regionprops` to get the centroids, and then plot them.

Code:

```
clear
clc

BW = im2bw(imread('Notes.png'));
BW = imclearborder(BW);

%//Erode the image with a disk structuring element to obtain circleish
%// shapes.
se = strel('disk',2);        
erodedBW = imerode(BW,se);
```

Here `erodedBW` looks like this:

[image]

```
%// Erode again with a line oriented at 15 degrees (to ~ match orientation of major axis of notes...very approximate haha) 

se2 = strel('line',5,15);
erodedBW2 = imerode(erodedBW,se2);
```

`erodedBW2` looks like this:

[image]

Then find centroids and plot them

```
S = regionprops(erodedBW2,'Centroid');

figure;
imshow(BW)
hold on
for k = 1:numel(S)

   scatter(S(k).Centroid(:,1), S(k).Centroid(:,2),60,'filled')

end
```

Output:

[image]

Empty notes are not detected but that's manageable using other morphological operations I guess.

Hope that helps!

Comment: To detect the empty notes, perhaps apply the same operation on the **reverse** of the image.  Either way, this is more than what the OP deserved.  Bravo! +1.

Comment: Oh good idea @rayryeng I had not thought about that! I tried using the line `strel` before the disk but the result was not good and I felt too lazy to deep further :) Thanks for the +1!

Comment: You also may need to do a `bwareaopen` because if we apply the same logic on the inverse, there still may be some noise... like the hole at the top of the treble clef at the top of the staff for example... still, very good!

Comment: Yep good idea! I must say that I was not expecting `imerode` to clean that much stuff as easily :)

Comment: What if you just fill the empty notes before applying the disk element? I can't see any other element that has an empty centre and is that small. Very nice work though. +1 from me as well.

Comment: Yes @kkuilla I tried to fill empty notes before applying the disk element, however because of the clefs on the left I was left with them at the end. Maybe the parameters I used were not correct though. I'll give it another try today lol

Comment: lol what do you mean @onlyappleapp? I'm not sure to understand haha :) Does it solve your problem?

Comment: of curse ! You make a disk and then find thing that are like that disk ! I use  filters to fill them up but it take a lot of mistakes !!

Comment: haha great then! If this helped you can you mark the answer as accepted please? Thanks! That was a fun problem!

Comment: Excuse me , I forgot . Can you do the empty notes ?

Comment: no problem! For the empty notes I'll try a bit later today

Comment: :/ I don't think you answer that .

Comment: Oh shoot I completely forgot to give you feedback about that sorry :) Actually I tried a coulpe things that works only partially.

Comment: Ok so you un-accepted the answer? Did you actually try anything on your own?